# Dependency Injection with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection

I am using wanger npm pkg, and it works fine... But I don't know how to separate files when using DI.

Here is my routes:

```
var logic = require('./logic');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


/**
 * 
 * Routes /api/v*
 * 
 * @param {obj} wagner
 * @returns {obj}
 */
module.exports = function (wagner) 
{

    var api = express.Router();
    api.use(bodyParser.json());

    api.get('/me', logic.me);

    return api;
}
```

and here is logic.me function:

```
var me = {
    me: function (req, res) {
        res.send("TEST");
    }
}

module.exports = me;
```

What I wanna do is to be able to use `wagner` inside my `logic.me` function... How can I achive that?

Comment: Export not an object, but a function that accepts `wagner` as its argument and returns `me` object.

Comment: Could you show me example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you could define your `logic`

```
function meWrapper(wagner) {
    var me = {
        me: function (req, res) {
            res.send("TEST");
        }
    }

    return me;
}

module.exports = meWrapper;
```

and that's how you would use it later:

```
module.exports = function (wagner) 
{

    var api = express.Router();
    api.use(bodyParser.json());

    api.get('/me', logic(wagner).me);

    return api;
}
```